# Flexbox и распределение

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

Я полный новичок в верстке, поработав с флексами многое понял, но почему-то не получается сделать так, как я хочу:(
 На картинке красной рамочкой я отметил место, где я хочу чтобы находилась моя картинка и линиями я отметил мой тег `<p>`.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, заранее спасибо вам!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i');

body {
 margin: 0;
 font: 16px/1.5 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.hero {
 position: relative;
 height: 100vh;
 padding: 20px 100px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 
 align-items: center;
 background-color: #333;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: top;
 background-image: url(../img/aboutbg.jpg);

}

.hero-title {
 margin: 0px 0 0 0;
 font-size: 70px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #fff;
}

.hero-title2 {
 font-size: 30px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #fff;
}

.twoconth2 {
 font-size: 50px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #000;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}

.twocontp {
 font-size: 25px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}

.imageleft {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}

.polytech {
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.opisaniek {
 margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>About</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleabout.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="hero" data-id="about">
        <h1 class="hero-title">Обо мне</h1>
        <h2 class="hero-title2">Моя биография и тд</h2>
    </header>
    <section id="services">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">
                <h2 class="twoconth2">-Учебное заведение-</h2>
                <p class="twocontp">Политехнический колледж</p>
            </div>
            <div class="imageleft">
                <img class="polytech" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRDkFvuphkCXqbMjEKQalUTAW53wCpba3yBeqxGkJOK6ocRLUyE">
                <div class="textpodimage">
                    <p class="opisaniek">Образование: студент 4 курса</p>
                    <p class="opisaniek">Специальность: «Информационные системы»</p>
                    <p class="opisaniek">Квалификация - техник-программист</p>
                    <p class="opisaniek">Политехнический колледж г.Астана</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что бы здесь смогли вам помочь будет проще если вы дайте еще нам и код той части (`css` то же) что вы хотите заменить.

Comment: Извините пожалуйста, но так как я новичок, у меня этого сделать не получилось, извиняюсь -_-

Comment: Просто скопируете часть `html` и `css` кода который для этой части здесь в `snippet`. https://i.stack.imgur.com/522IS.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZTpT.png

Comment: Делал с Middle(ом) Фронт-енд разработчиком, хороший знакомый, так что этот код 100% правильный, проверили. Можете использовать, друзья!

Comment: Большое спасибо выше человеку, который показал, как можно скинуть html и css документ, огромное человеческое спасибо, мне как новичку трудно разобраться было

Comment: Посмотрите ваш код, здесь уже картинка с лева, Так и вы хотели, может на вашем сайте есть другие стили что мешают картинке? посмотрите все это в `F12`, Смотрите там какие стили накладываются или на картинку или в ее контейнер.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас в селекторе `imageleft` указано свойство `justify-content: center;` его надо заменить на `justify-content: space-between;` и дальше отрегулировать отступы.

Также думаю в селекторе `.hero` убрать флексы,текст можно выравнять задав в селекторах `.hero-title` и `.hero-title2` свойство `text-align: center;`, тоже касается селектора `.twoconth2`,хотя здесь я считаю это ошибкой и надо использовать `text-align: center;`.На валидацию документ выдает ошибку из-за отсутствия атрибута `alt` у тега `img`.

Comment: Я уже всё сделал и в коде всё правильно в идеале, спасибо